# Telerik RadGrid inside modalpopup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

So, as the title suggests ;)  I'm trying to place a databound RadGrid inside a modal popup.  I've fiddled with Telerik's examples without luck. I seem to be having two principal problems, likely because of my inexperience.  One is that I need to trigger it from an already extant itemcontrol in the grid. The other is that it doesn't seem like the popup extender plays nicely with the Telerik script manager and if I try to add an ASP script manager I get an exception.

As always, I'm very grateful for any suggestions!
Thanks!

Comment: Is your popup content on the page already, or does it contain a separate window?  Are you loading the RadGrid based on an argument from the parent page?

Comment: @Seano666 At the moment I have the grid within a placeholder that I show/hide when the databinding is triggered by an item command.  I'd like to trigger the modal popup the same way... thanks for any input!

Comment: After your databinding you could use the VisibleOnPageLoad property of the RadWindow.  Hopefully I am understanding your requirement correctly.  http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-open-rad-window-from-codebehind-in-c

Comment: Try this approach http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window

Comment: @Seano666 Thank you... that's exactly what I wound up doing.  Seems to work fine.  Thank you!

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 Great, I'll make an official answer then, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your databinding you could use the VisibleOnPageLoad property of the RadWindow.

```
Control.DataBind()
RadWindow1.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
```